# Why can't I allocate memory for a string using [] in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

For the getline() function, I tried two method to allocate memory space for  string, but the first one works, the second doesn't. Can anyone explain why the second won't work?

The first one

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int bytes_read;
  int nbytes = 100;
  char *my_string;

  puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

  /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
  my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

  if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
      puts ("ERROR!");
    }
  else
    {
      puts ("You typed:");
      puts (my_string);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The second one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int bytes_read;
  int nbytes = 100;
  char my_string[nbytes+1];

  puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

  /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

  if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
      puts ("ERROR!");
    }
  else
    {
      puts ("You typed:");
      puts (my_string);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The second one can be compiled, but when I execute it:

```
bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
Please enter a line of text.
lsdfa
Bus error: 10
```

It says Bus error: 10

I don't know what is the possible reason, can anyone help me?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it the fact that you're using variable-length arrays?

Comment: It just says 'Bus error: 10'.

Comment: Which language? C or C++? They are very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The signature for `getline` requires a pointer to a `char*` so that it may be modified](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html). This is because `getline` is supposed to be allowed to call `realloc` on the `char*` or allocate a `char*` if you pass a `char*` which points to 0:

> `getline()` reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer
>         containing the text into `*lineptr`.
>
> ...
>
> In either case, on a successful call, `*lineptr` and `*n` will be updated to
>         reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively

In the first case everything is fine as the pointer you've passed to `getline` can be modified.

In the second case you're passing a pointer to a `char` array, which itself cannot be modified. As you've found, unfortunately `&my_string` ends up looking like `char**`, so the compiler does not complain (but it may with `-Wall`).

Basically, since `getline` needs to be able to modify what `lineptr` points to, in your second case this cannot be done (hence the bus error).

Answer (score 3):

Read the manpage for `getline()`:

Exerpt:

> Alternatively, before calling  getline(),  *lineptr  can  contain  a  pointer  to  a  malloc(3)-allocated  buffer  *n bytes in size.

So `getline()` specifically assumes that the buffer passed to it has been allocated with `malloc` so that it can resize it to a bigger size if necessary.

You should have gotten a compiler warning such as this one that tips you off to the fact that something's wrong with the way you're calling the function:

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘getline’ from incompatible pointer type

Comment: +1, but it only plays with the pointer if the size isn't sufficient. Granted this effectively means you should allocate the pointer with `malloc`. In either case, passing a pointer to a `char` array is wrong per the remarks that `getline` stores the address of the buffer containing the text in `*lineptr`. Can't do that with the address of a `char` array.

Answer (score 2):

I actually can't make much sense of this.  Neither of your examples should compile from what I can tell...nowhere close to it in fact.  Do it this way:

```
int main() {

  std::string line;

...
  std::getline(std::cin, line);

...
}
```

No having to mess with malloc, new, any of that...

And include `iostream`, not `stdio.h`!

Comment: *"I actually can't make much sense of this. Neither of your examples should compile from what I can tell"* The OP, despite the tagging, has written c.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'new' keyword for dynamic initialization:

```
char* my_string = new char[nBytes + 1];
```

Comment: C++ specific when the OP's code is (while generic enough to compile with either) idiomatically c.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected version:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFLEN 100

int main()
{
  int bytes_read;
  int nbytes = BUFLEN;
  char *my_string = NULL;

  puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

  /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

  if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
      puts ("ERROR!");
    }
  else
    {
      puts ("You typed:");
      puts (my_string);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Frankly, I would prefer "fgets()" instead of "getline()":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFLEN 100

int main()
{
  char my_string[BUFLEN+1];

  puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

  /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
  fgets (my_string, BUFLEN, stdin);
  ...
```

If you're in C++-land, you're probably best off using std::string.

Comment: Not so. `getline` takes a `char**` allocated with `malloc`.